# Como evitar chamar a mesma função várias vezes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho dois arquivos scripts, um para acessar um arquivo CSV, transformar cada linha em um dicionario e retornar uma lista de dicionários (linhas).

Meu segundo script é uma função para criar uma nova coluna no arquivo (C1), copiar os dados de outra coluna (C2) para esta nova (C1) e excluir a coluna antiga (C2). O objetivo disso é alterar o nome de colunas no arquivo CSV criando cópias com nomes diferentes, porém para alterar estas devo chamar a mesma função várias vezes apenas alterando os parâmetros que são os nomes antigos e novos utilizados. Como posso fazer isto sem ter que chamar a função toda hora?

Arquivo 1: acessar_csv

```
import unicodecsv


def ler_csv(arquivo):
    with open(arquivo, 'rb') as dados:
        dicionario = unicodecsv.DictReader(dados)
        return list(dicionario)

inscricoes = ler_csv('inscriçoes.csv')
envolvimento_diario = ler_csv('envolvimento_diario.csv')
submissoes_de_projetos = ler_csv('submissoes_de_projetos.csv')
```

Arquivo 2: alterar_nome

```
from acessar_csv import envolvimento_diario, inscricoes, submissoes_de_projetos


# Alterar nome das colunas de inglês para português

def alterar_nome(arquivo, colunaIngles, colunaPortugues): # Função para alterar nome das colunas, recebendo como argumentos o arquivo que será alterado, o nome da coluna em Inglês (atual) e o novo nome em português
    for coluna in arquivo:
        coluna[colunaPortugues] = coluna[colunaIngles] # Cria uma nova coluna (colunaPortugues) cujos valores são iguais ao da colunaIngles
        del[coluna[colunaIngles]] # Deleta a colunaIngles


# Chamada de função para alterar o nome das colunas do arquivo envolvimento_diario

alterar_nome(envolvimento_diario, 'acct', 'id_conta')
alterar_nome(envolvimento_diario, 'utc_date', 'data_coleta_dados')
alterar_nome(envolvimento_diario, 'num_courses_visited', 'num_cursos_visitados')
alterar_nome(envolvimento_diario, 'total_minutes_visited', 'total_minutos_visitados')
alterar_nome(envolvimento_diario, 'lessons_completed', 'lições_completadas')
alterar_nome(envolvimento_diario, 'projects_completed', 'projetos_completos')

# Chamada de função para alterar o nome das colunas do arquivo inscricoes

alterar_nome(inscricoes, 'account_key', 'id_conta')
alterar_nome(inscricoes, 'status', 'status_inscrição')
alterar_nome(inscricoes, 'join_date', 'data_inscrição_curso')
alterar_nome(inscricoes, 'cancel_date', 'data_cancelamento_inscrição')
alterar_nome(inscricoes, 'days_to_cancel', 'dias_até_cancelamento')
alterar_nome(inscricoes, 'is_udacity', 'conta_teste')
alterar_nome(inscricoes, 'is_canceled', 'cancelamento_data_coleta_dados')

# Chamada de função para alterar o nome das colunas do arquivo submissoes_de_projetos

alterar_nome(submissoes_de_projetos, 'creation_date', 'data_submissão_projeto')
alterar_nome(submissoes_de_projetos, 'completion_date', 'data_avaliação_projeto')
alterar_nome(submissoes_de_projetos, 'assigned_rating', 'status_avaliação_projeto')
alterar_nome(submissoes_de_projetos, 'account_key', 'id_conta')
alterar_nome(submissoes_de_projetos, 'lesson_key', 'id_projeto')
alterar_nome(submissoes_de_projetos, 'processing_state', 'status_processo_avaliação')

print (envolvimento_diario[0])
print (inscricoes[0])
print (submissoes_de_projetos[0])
```

Tentei fazer isto com um dicionário como na pergunta a seguir, porém não consegui:
[Erro: unhashable type: 'dict_keys', como resolver?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258274/erro-unhashable-type-dict-keys-como-resolver/)

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Crie um dicionário com todas as Chaves (palavras em inglês) e seus respectivos valores (palavras em português).

import csv

```
# Caminho do arquivo CSV que será manipulado
csv_file = "ARQUIVO_CSV.csv"

# Dicionário contendo as traduções de inglês para português
# TODO: Armazenar os dados abaixo em um arquivo externo ou banco de dados
traducoes = {'acct': 'id_conta', 
             'utc_date':'data_coleta_dados',
             'num_courses_visited': 'num_cursos_visitados'}

# Lista para armazenar os nomes das colunas do arquivo CSV
csv_data = list()
```

2. Altere os parâmetros da função alterar_nome para que receba apenas o nome do arquivo. No corpo da função faça um loop lendo cada uma das colunas e procurando no dicionário se da match com alguma chave, se sim então altera no arquivo aquela coluna para o valor em português, se não segue o loop até o fim do arquivo.

`# Abre o arquivo CSV como somente leitura e faz um loop nas colunas da linha 1 do arquivo CSV (Cabeçalho)
        verificando se existe uma palavra em português correspondente no dicionário definido acima e adiciona na lista csv_data.
        No final do processo a lista csv_data terá as palavras traduzidas e as que não forem encontradas serão adicionadas
        na sua versão em inglês`

```
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    csv_data.clear()
    # Just a cool way to represent the first line of the file
    header = 1
    try:
        for row in reader:
            if reader.line_num == header:
                for column in row:
                    if column.strip() in traducoes.keys():
                        csv_data.append(traducoes.get(column.strip()))
            else:
                csv_data.append(column.strip())
    f.close()
    except csv.Error as e:
        f.close()
        sys.exit('Erro durante a leitura do arquivo %s, na linha %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

3. Abre o arquivo CSV original dessa vez como escrita e altera os cabeçalhos em inglês para português de acordo com o que foi preenchido na lista csv_data:

`# Abre o arquivo CSV como escrita e escreve nas colunas do arquivo o conteúdo generado na lista csv_data`

```
with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
    delimiter = ", "
    col_count = 1
    try:
        for data in csv_data:
            if col_count < len(csv_data):
                f.write(data + delimiter)
            else:
                f.write(data)
            col_count += 1
    f.close()
    except IOError as ioe:
        f.close()
        sys.exit('Erro durante a escrita do arquivo %s, %s' % (filename, ioe))
```

Comment: Olá, desculpe a pergunta, pode parecer bobagem mas é que sou novo em programação. É mais ou menos o que tentei fazer neste código: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258274/erro-unhashable-type-dict-keys-como-resolver/ ? Se sim, o que eu deveria alterar?

Comment: Sim é parecido com isso, consegue mostrar as cinco primeiras linhas do arquivo CSV?

Comment: Olá, claro!

Peguei as 10 primeiras: https://imgur.com/a/Lssx0

Este é o arquivo envolvimento_diario

Comment: Cristhian Miguel, tá aí o código que traduz as colunas do arquivo CSV, agora é só colocar em métodos conforme sua necessidade, ou transformar em um script que você chame pela linha de comando e passe parâmetros. Tudo depende da necessidade. Espero ter ajudado. Abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado, realmente ajudou!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Não esquece de dar upvote na resposta. Abraço.

Comment: Claro, está feito!

Comment: Também adicionei o código no Github para futuras referências.
https://github.com/klebercsilva/csv_headers_translator